# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll error occurred?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Am getting error Unbound Expression. I Created a new column & Unbounded Expression on Runtime.  I get a particular cell values(GetRowCellValue) from gridview and try to change that unbound expression column with new value(SetRowCellValue). But error shown whats my mistake ? Help me.

This is my Code.

```
private void unbound2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'orionSystemDataSet.Test_Product' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.test_ProductTableAdapter.Fill(this.orionSystemDataSet.Test_Product);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'orionSystemDataSet.Test_Gridview' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.test_GridviewTableAdapter.Fill(this.orionSystemDataSet.Test_Gridview);


        var product = repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1.View.Columns.AddField("Type");
        product.Visible = true;


        //create unbound column in form load
        unboundcreate();

    }

    private void unboundcreate()
    {
        gridControl1.ForceInitialize();

        GridColumn unbColumn = gridView1.Columns.AddField("PriceQuantity");
        unbColumn.Caption = "PricQuan";
        unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gridView1.Columns.Count;
        unbColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
        unbColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
        unbColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
        unbColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "c";
        unbColumn.AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
        unbColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
        unbColumn.UnboundExpression = "[Quantity] * [Each]";

    }
```

Code to get value & set value

```
 private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {

            GridView view = sender as GridView;


            if (e.Column.FieldName == "PriceQuantity" && e.IsGetData)
            {
                //e.Value = getTotalValue(view, e.ListSourceRowIndex);
                calfun();
            }
            else
            {
                // nothing
            }

    }


    private void calfun()
    {
        if (gridView1.FocusedRowHandle >= 1)
        {

            string temp = "Discount";
            //string dis = TXE_Gettype.Text.ToString();
            object objec = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Type"]);
            string dis = objec.ToString();

            if (dis == temp)
            {
                object obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle - 1, gridView1.Columns["Each"]);

                int aa = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
                //textEdit1.Text = aa.ToString();

                object obj1 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Each"]);

                int a = Convert.ToInt32(obj1);
                int b = aa;

                int c = a * b;

                //textEdit2.Text = c.ToString();

                gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["PriceQuantity"], c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            }
    }
```

Help me Please I want to get & set value

Comment: My guess is that it is your call to `gridView1.SetRowCellValue` that causes `gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData` event to be called

Comment: Hi Jens, If i modify SetRowCellValue to gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData it shows error like "The CustomUnboundColumnData event can only appears left hand side of += or =+ "

Comment: yes ofc :D hehe, why would you do that? instead of using `gridView1...` try and see if the `e` variable can be used instead..

Comment: Hi Jens, :D Am new to c# that's why.... No e. is not working there because it is outside that function so.

Comment: Sure, "e" is outside of "calfun"... but you must pass it as an argument, or move  your code in the event handler. Your "calfunc" as it is not clean.

Answer (score 2):

The last couple of frames of your stacktrace could be usefull... even with all this code, we can only speculate.

But I agree with JensKloster's comment: DevExpress unbound columns are made to display unbound columns (computed, from others, then).

The event is here to make you compute this value. It is called each time you change something in your row.
Thus, calling setvalue from it will cause the method to call it itself. (=> stack overflow exception)

Use `e.Value = myValue` to set your value:

```
e.Value = c;
```

instead of

```
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["PriceQuantity"], c);
```

where e is the DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs given as an argument of your event.

**edit:** Moreover, I guess that when using `gridView1.FocusedRowHandle`, you were refering to `e.RowHandle` ? See [this](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) to see what is given to you when this event is called.

**edit2:** why using custom mechanisms if you just want to multiply two columns ? `unbColumn.UnboundExpression = "[Quantity] * [Each]";` is sufficient, isnt it ?

Comment: I completly agree - I would think that `unbColumn.UnboundExpression = "[Quantity] * [Each]` is sifficient

Comment: Hi Jens & Olivier, My task is to obtain "discount on previous item" in Gridview, so I need to get a cell value on previous row & get the cell value in current row, so I used `(FocusedRowHandle)`. Then I want to multiply both values and obtain new value. Finally that new value is want to stored in Unbound `Column[PriceQuantity]`.                   This are all done when i select 'Discount' in the `RepositoryLookupEdit` in the Bound Column. If I select any other Item from RepositoryLookupEdit then 'Discount' I need to calculate `Unbound Expression[Quantity]*[Each].` Help me to complete my task ?